# Delete rows in Tabulator : cannot delete rows using deleteRow()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabulator

I'm trying to delete rows from the bottom of the table with deleteRow() method in Tabulator(a javascript table library) associated with vue.js `v-on` directive, but it does not work.

I have tried with `table.deleteRow(1)` (arg is the row index according to the documentation) but returns the error though it has the index 1 row.

```
  methods: {
      myDeleteRow: this.anyTable.deleteRow(1)
    }
  }
```

```
tabulator.js?6dbe:7464 Uncaught (in promise) Delete Error - No matching row found
(anonymous) @   tabulator.js?6dbe:7464
Tabulator.deleteRow @   tabulator.js?6dbe:7447
myDeleteRow @   TermsConditions.vue?2be7:95
invoker @   vue.esm.js?efeb:2128
fn._withTask.fn._withTask   @   vue.esm.js?efeb:1913

Delete Error - No matching row found: 1

tabulator.js?6dbe:7464 Uncaught (in promise) Delete Error - No matching row found
(anonymous) @   tabulator.js?6dbe:7464
Tabulator.deleteRow @   tabulator.js?6dbe:7447
myDeleteRow @   TermsConditions.vue?2be7:95
invoker @   vue.esm.js?efeb:2128
fn._withTask.fn._withTask   @   vue.esm.js?efeb:1913
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the argument for `deleteRow(index)` is called `index`, but it acts more as a record ID.  If you look at the `index` option on the table configuration object, `index` is an ID field associated with each record of the table data that you specify.  Tabulator doesn't really help when it comes to performing actions on the actual row count index, so you must heavily rely on some kind of row identifier.